# Отображение загруженных фотографий на странице по примеру Вконтакте

Tags: jquery, php, вконтакте, javascript

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать функционал отображения фотографий на странице по-примеру отображения фотографий на странице как во Вконтакте или может уже существуют готовые решения, кто может быть сталкивался с подобной задачей.

Пример отображения фотографий:

[image]

Comment: посмотри как это реализуется в вк

Comment: В чем проблема? Что пытались сделать? С чем столкнулись?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите вот этот скрипт: [jMosaic](https://github.com/absentik/jMosaic)

Подобных скриптов много.